# jq error (at <stdin>:25): Cannot index string with string "data1"

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file with data as below :

```json
{
  "0cef7017-e6af-4c92-9e7c-4db1d7afc733": {
    "Show": [
      "TEST1",
      "TEST2"
    ],
    "data1": 12345,
    "data2": 1234,
    "name": "Amit",
    "Ref": "group_1",
    "data3": 123
  },
  "metadata": "ThRsmflXIMA5LVlOI8vJ0OoSokw=",
  "eef75ad4-c733-42ac-9c55-dd5aa2d69fad": {
    "Show": [
      "TEST3",
      "TEST4"
    ],
    "data1": 12345,
    "data2": 1234,
    "name": "Anuj",
    "Ref": "group_2",
    "data3": 123
  }
}
```

I want an output like :

```
12345,Amit
12345,Anuj
```

I tried below command :

```
cat AV | jq  '.[]|."data1",."name"'
12345
Amit
jq: error (at <stdin>:25): Cannot index string with string "data1"
```

It is not giving the expected output. It seems it is not parsing completely as data1 string not appearing at metadata

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
cat AV |jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.key != "metadata") |.value |"\(.data1), \(.name)"'
```

where the element with key value `metadata` is removed. Since the error raises due to `metadata`, which's one the outermost keys , having no sub-element with key name `data1` or `name`

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/j5YzkZfgWx)</kbd>

Comment: `| "\(.data1), \(.name)"` would suffice; if using jq 1.5 or later, an alternative would be: `| [.data1, .name] | join(",")`

Comment: exactly, thanks @peak

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive descent `..`.

Filter

```
[[.. | (.data1?) | select(.!=null)], [.. | (.name?) | select(.!=null)]] 
| transpose[] 
| @csv
```

Input

```
{
  "0cef7017-e6af-4c92-9e7c-4db1d7afc733": {
    "Show": [
      "TEST1",
      "TEST2"
    ],
    "data1": 12345,
    "data2": 1234,
    "name": "Amit",
    "Ref": "group_1",
    "data3": 123
  },
  "metadata": "ThRsmflXIMA5LVlOI8vJ0OoSokw=",
  "eef75ad4-c733-42ac-9c55-dd5aa2d69fad": {
    "Show": [
      "TEST3",
      "TEST4"
    ],
    "data1": 12345,
    "data2": 1234,
    "name": "Anuj",
    "Ref": "group_2",
    "data3": 123
  }
}
```

Output

```
12345,"Amit"
12345,"Anuj"
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/l9OGsI3hFq